# Batch script to merge videos in directories

Tags: windows-8, batch-file

I need a batch script to list *.avi|*.mp4 and run a command for all directories that contain such files:

```
mencoder.exe <some_arguments> -o "output/(name_of_directory).mp4" <list_of_files_in_directory_spearated_by_spaces_evey_file_quoted>
```

Could anybody help me with that? Is it possible at all?

I made a script in PHP, compiled it with BamCompile, but it seems to act totally different on Windows 8, arrays are being converted to strings and something really weird is goin on...

Comment: Do the list of files all need fully qualified paths?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@echo off &setlocal
cd /d "%userprofile%\Videos"
for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d *.avi *.mp4^|findstr /n $') do set "$%%a=%%~b"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%a in ('set "$" 2^>nul') do set "line=!line! "%%~b""

echo mencoder.exe [some_arguments] -o "output/(name_of_directory).mp4" %line%
```

Look at the output and remove `echo` if it looks good.

Comment: `(name_of_directory`) did not change and generally nothing happens, it says `could not find the file`... is it recursive?

Answer (score 0):

See if this floats your boat.  `!` characters are verboten in paths and filenames.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cd /d "%userprofile%\Videos"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b /a-d *.avi *.mp4') do (
   for /f "delims=" %%b in ("%%~dpa.") do (
        set "line="
        for %%c in ("%%~dpa*.*") do set line=!line! "%%c"
        echo mencoder.exe [some_arguments] -o "output\%%~nxb.mp4" !line!
        pause
   )
)
```